# I want to get most dialed and recieved contact from call log

Tags: java, android

i want to get one number who is most appeared in call logs, for example 12345 is a number and it is most dialed, recieved and missed called number and i want to get it.

here is what i'm trying:

```
 private String getCallDetails() {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append("Call Details :");
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode) {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            dir = "OUTGOING";
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            dir = "INCOMING";
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            dir = "MISSED";
            break;
        }
        sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- "
                + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime
                + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
        sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
    }
    managedCursor.close();
    return sb.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [CONTENT_FREQUENT_URI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_FREQUENT_URI) in `ContactsContract.Contacts`. An example of its usage is given [here](https://github.com/evgeniysharafan/Utils/blob/master/utils/src/main/java/com/evgeniysharafan/utils/ContactUtils.java#L270)